# Cookie value cannot be read until I've logged into the WP admin

Tags: wp-admin, cookies

Once logged into the WP admin, I can refresh the front-end and see my cookie's value outputted as "hello world". If I log out of the admin, then refresh my front-end, the cookie's value is now "nothing", as seen in my example function.

This only happens when I'm viewing the website online. When testing locally, I can read the cookie without being logged into the WP admin. Any ideas?

Here's my test function for setting the cookie

```
function test_cookie() {
    setcookie( 'test-cookie', 'hello world', time()+1209600, '/');
}
add_action( 'init', 'test_cookie' );
```

Here's the function for outputting the cookie's value onto the page

```
function output_test_cookie() {

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['test-cookie'] ) )
        echo $_COOKIE["test-cookie"]; // should output hello world, but only does this when logged into WP admin
    else
        echo 'nothing';
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'output_test_cookie' );
```

Comment: you don't have to be, it's probably your use of the `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constants that's causing the issue. why are you using them and what are they set to? you normally don't need these unless you have an unusual configuration.

Comment: @Milo I saw these in another example on settings cookies with WordPress. I've updated my question with these constants removed. I still have the same issue though, just can't work out why the cookie is only set after I log in to the admin.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is set at the beginning of a request, if you're trying to access the value in `$_COOKIE` in the same request as the call to `setcookie`, it won't exist until the next request.

Comment: @Milo I'm aware that the cookie is not set until the next page refresh but that's not the issue I'm facing. I've just tried my code in the theme's functions.php instead of plugin and same issue.

Comment: It's almost like I need to be authenticated before it will allow any cookies to be set. Could this be a server setting?

Comment: the only other thing I can guess is that output is being sent before you set the cookie. have you tried this with no plugins and unaltered default theme?

Comment: @Milo one step closer now. I reverted back to Twenty Twelve but kept only my plugin (it has the example code in this question in it). Now I don't need to be logged into the admin for the cookie to be set, but I cannot output the value of the cookie on the page using my function above, until I log into the admin. So still something weird going on...

Answer (score 3):

It appears I needed to use an earlier hook. Using the `wp` or `init` action hooks allow me to read the cookie's value without logging into the admin first.

```
function output_test_cookie() {

if ( isset( $_COOKIE['test-cookie'] ) )
    echo $_COOKIE["test-cookie"];
}
add_action( 'wp', 'output_test_cookie' ); // wp or init is needed
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is necessary under whatever strange conditions you've got going on. In a vanilla WP install with twentytwelve it's possible to read cookies anywhere after they're properly set. Using your code to set the cookie, I can read it in the template just fine.

Comment: @Milo testing online or locally? I'm also running it from a plugin file, not a template. Everything works perfectly locally for me.

Comment: on a LAMP server, it shouldn't matter if it's online or not. hooks are hooks, whether they're in a plugin or a theme, my point was it should be possible to read the cookie anywhere, from init to wp_footer, there's nothing in WordPress that would prevent this.